# how to send a value of foreach loop form using ajax in laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, html, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm trying to send value from form to controller, but the error is all forms send the value as a first form, but I want each form to send the data inside it when I press the send button.

**Blade**

```
@foreach($car_lists as $car_list)
<li class="item odd cars_data">
    <form style="display:flex;" id="addcurrency">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="{{@session('amount')}} {{$car_list->price}}">
        <span class="result"> {{$car_list->price}}</span>
        <span class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center w-24px h-22px 
            bg-gray-300 rounded cursor-pointer undefined result_symb addCurrency">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10px" height="11px" viewBox="0 0 10 11">
                <path id="GEL" d="M313.914-18v-1.689h-3.663a2.938,2.938,0,0,1-1.643-.46,3,3,0,0,1-1.089-1.3,4.608,4.608,0,0,1-.384-1.94,5,5,0,0,1,.343-1.987,2.543,2.543,0,0,1,1.112-1.225v3.372h.894v-3.64a2.492,2.492,0,0,1,.48-.044,2.936,2.936,0,0,1,.5.044v3.64h.894V-26.6a2.469,2.469,0,0,1,1.134,1.24,5.547,5.547,0,0,1,.343,2.132H315a6.022,6.022,0,0,0-.439-2.324,4.874,4.874,0,0,0-1.263-1.8,4.534,4.534,0,0,0-1.939-1.019V-29h-.894v.472l-.236-.007q-.081-.007-.236-.007-.347,0-.51.015V-29h-.894v.631a4.67,4.67,0,0,0-1.891.982,4.823,4.823,0,0,0-1.256,1.671A4.872,4.872,0,0,0,305-23.67a5.7,5.7,0,0,0,.229,1.61,4.62,4.62,0,0,0,.672,1.4,3.294,3.294,0,0,0,1.056.968v.058h-1.411V-18Z" 
                      transform="translate(-305 29)" fill="#272a37">
                </path>
            </svg>
        </span>
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
</li>
@endforeach
```

So how to I fix this that I'd send from each form to my controller with ajax?

**Ajax**

```
$('#addcurrency').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    var currency = $(this);
    var currency_id = $(currency).closest('.cars_data').find('.car_id').val();
    var data = $(currency).closest('.cars_data').find('#addcurrency').serializeArray();
    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/convert",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            $(currency).closest('.cars_data').find('.result').html(response.count);
        }
    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
use AmrShawky\LaravelCurrency\Facade\Currency;
use App\Models\Car;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CurrencyController extends Controller
{
    public function convert(Request $request)
    {
        $converted = Currency::convert()
            ->from('GEL')
            ->to('USD')
            ->amount($request->amount)
            ->round(-2)
            ->get();

        return response()->json(['count' => $converted]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't repeat the same id on each form. Element ids are unique by definition. Use a class instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ids must be unique, otherwise only the first id works. you can try class instead of id:

```php
...
<form class='addcurrency'>
...
$('.addcurrency').on('submit'....
```